# Can't locate Config/IniFiles.pm in @INC (@INC contains:

Tags: centos, perl

mylvmbackup is a Perl script for quickly creating MySQL backups. It uses LVM's snapshot feature to do so. Following are the error I had when I tried to execute the mylvmbackup perl script. How can I resolve this issue ?

OS version : Cent OS 5.5

Perl Version: V5.8.8

```
[root@localhost mylvmbackup-0.13]# ./mylvmbackup --user=root --password=test --mycnf=/etc/mysql/my.cnf --vgname=vol_mygroup --lvname=mysql --backuptype=tar 
Can't locate Config/IniFiles.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8 .) at ./mylvmbackup line 20.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved it by following the step given below. :)

```
1) perl -MCPAN -e 'install Perl::OSType'

2) perl -MCPAN -e 'install Module::Build';

3) cpan install Config::IniFiles
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to have [Config-IniFiles](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Config-IniFiles/lib/Config/IniFiles.pm) installed for the script to work. Check your package repository for a package (better), or install via cpan (easier):

```
cpan install Config::IniFiles
```

Comment: While executing "cpan install Config::IniFiles" it gives the following error --> Can't locate Module/Build/Compat.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8 .) at Makefile.PL line 2.

Comment: You need other modules... why not try installing it with yum? -> "yum install perl-Config-IniFiles" (hope it's there)

Comment: No package perl-Config-IniFiles available.